# \edtext syntax error with macro

Tags: eledmac

With the newest `eledmac` package syntax errors of the `\edtext` command are reported, which is really helpful. In order to find my syntax error, I now have a question about reading the console log output, because I'm just not able to find my error.

In the console I get:

`MyFile.tex:200: Package eledmac Error: edtext without Xfootnote. Check syntaxis.`

What me puzzles the most is that I'm using my own command for `\edtext` which looks like the following and was tested with other documents:

\newcommand{\Apparatus}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Afootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}

On every occasion of this command the syntax seems to be ok. But wherelse can I look? Do I have to change the syntax of my `\newcommand{\Apparatus}…`?

---

EDIT: I think it has something to do with the optional argument I'm using with `\pend[]`: If you comment out the `\ledsiedenote` within `\parbox` the error concerning the missing Xfootnote of the `\edtext` command disappears. Is it because `\ledsidenote` can only be used within `\pstart \pend`. Here is a minimal example for that, that also runs out of page sync:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,DIV=12,BCOR=12mm]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{typearea}
\usepackage[ngerman, polutonikogreek, latin]{babel}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\usepackage{eledpar}
\footparagraph{A}
\newcommand{\AAp}[4]{\edtext{#1}{\lemma{#2}\Afootnote{#3 \textit{#4}}}}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%Fonts
\setkomafont{paragraph}{\normalfont\bfseries}


\begin{document}
\lineation{page}
\lineationR{page}
\begin{pages}
\begin{Leftside}
\selectlanguage{latin}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\eledsubsection*{Title}
\pend\pstart\itshape
Some text …
\pend[{
\parbox[h!][5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{img/afile.png}//\ledsidenote{[12]}\end{center}
}
}]
\endnumbering
\end{Leftside}

\begin{Rightside}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\beginnumberingR
\pstart
\eledsubsection*{Title}
\pend\pstart
Some parallel text …
\pend[{
\parbox[h!][5cm][c]{\textwidth}{\begin{center}
blabla
\end{center}
}
}]
\endnumberingR
\end{Rightside}
\Pages
\end{pages}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it contains a complete example code which reproduces the problem. Without this it may be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: I hope this is ok as an example.

Comment: The example generates the error `! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 \eledsubsection` not the error you describe, also what is the intention of `\parbox[h!]` (it doesn't do anything useful the only options are `t` `c` or `b`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you add in the optional argument of \pend or \pstart is not considered as a numbered text. So, it's not possible to use \ledsidenote inside. Maybe try with normal \marginpar. The eledmac message is not so ok, because, indeed, \ledsidenote call \edtext. We should try the position of \ledsidenote in the \eledmac code, but there is so much type of syntaxis problem.

Comment: I also discovered that the problem was with \ledsidenote. It's good to know that this command calls \edtext. Unfortunatly in my document there are several of \ledsidenotes after these kind of \parbox commands but now I think, that I will integrate them into the following numbered paragraph.

Comment: or, try, as I said, to use the standard \marginpar